# How can i mege data from csv files?

Tags: r, import-from-excel

I want to perform an analysis of 2 stocks for a period from 2017-01-01  until 2020-04-14. Unfortunately, I struggle with importing data.
I was trying to import data from excel, limit data for the period from 2017-01-01  until 2020-04-14 and merge these data.

```
x <- read.csv("data/pkn_d.csv")
y <- read.csv("data/lts_d.csv")

head(x)
        Date   Open   High    Low  Close   Volume
1 1999-11-26 16.307 16.452 15.717 16.229 14845780
2 1999-11-29 16.154 16.229 15.863 15.940  5148506
3 1999-11-30 16.086 16.375 16.086 16.229  3077465
4 1999-12-01 16.375 16.742 16.229 16.742  2881475
5 1999-12-02 16.895 17.407 16.818 17.040  3093313
6 1999-12-03 17.040 17.330 16.895 17.260  2207547

head(y)
    Date   Open   High    Low  Close  Volume
1 2005-06-09 26.676 26.676 25.013 25.013 1795647
2 2005-06-10 25.097 25.433 24.594 24.594  679054
3 2005-06-13 25.013 25.097 24.594 24.762  213950
4 2005-06-14 24.929 24.929 24.762 24.762  181415
5 2005-06-15 24.762 24.845 24.594 24.762  160359
6 2005-06-16 24.762 24.762 24.350 24.350  171475
```

I'm only interested in data from 2017-01-01  until 2020-04-14 and 5th column (close price)

```
x <- x[4285:5100, 5]
y <- y[2899:3714, 5]
```

Next, I want to merge these data:

```
merge(x,y)
```

However, I don't obtain any meaningful output.. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: (1) Please cut your data down to something minimal but sufficient to illustrate and include it.  Please read the instructions for posting at the top of the [tag:r] page.  (2) Also the question refers to an "issue" but never states what the "issue" is.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question doesn't include a reproducible example, here is a solution that merges a set of stock prices retrieved from the internet via the `quantmod` package.

```
library("quantmod")
#
symbolList <- c("PKN","LTS")
from.dat <- as.Date("2017-01-01",format="%Y-%m-%d")
to.dat <- as.Date("2020-04-14",format="%Y-%m-%d")

prices <- lapply(symbolList,function(x){
     getSymbols(x,auto.assign = FALSE,from = from.dat,to = to.dat)[,4]
})
priceData <- do.call(merge,prices)
head(priceData)
```

...and the output:

```
> head(priceData)
           PKN.Close LTS.Close
2017-01-03    49.370      2.54
2017-01-04    50.370      2.57
2017-01-05    89.340      2.43
2017-01-06    89.340      2.38
2017-01-09    49.855      2.36
2017-01-10    88.300      2.44
>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution :) It's great!
However, I updated my question. Could you relook at this?